# How to link two files in Windows so that both are changed at the same time

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is it possible to link two files (let's say Word documents) in different locations on Windows so that when I edit one of the documents, the other gets updated to reflect those changes automatically?

Comment: Different locations means: different folders on the same volume? different volumes on the same PC? different PCs?

Comment: are the two files exactly the same or one file contains some linked content from the other file?

Comment: If files in question supposed to be on the same(!!!) file partitions (the same drive) then it pretty easy to do that by using hard links. At first, you need to create (or use existing) single original file, than create hard link to that file in different location as `mklink /H c:\dir123\hard-linked.txt c:\bla-bla\original-file.txt` In this case you can edit both files from different places but content will be the same.  *P.S. solution works only on NTFS partitions.*

Comment: Please expand what you mean by the files being in different locations. Is one on a network drive? Are they both on the same storage device? WHY are they in two different locations? The reason you need to add this information is that the "correct" answer will vary based on these further details. What works best in one situation may not work at all in another.

Answer (score 1):

I used Unison for similar task - it is available for Windows and is highly configurable so you can sync really any files or directories you want: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

If you feel Unison won't help you here is a fairly comprehensive list of similar software: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software